# how to replace the current launch image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to download an image and store it locally when I start my app,next time I run the app,Can I use that image to replace the current launch image?

How to do this?thanks

Comment: You mean the splash screen ? you cannot change that programmatically

Comment: You can't do this programmatically. So just download the image, size it to the appropriate size of phone dimension, go to images.xcasset, create a new launch image (+), then drag and drop the image into the iPhone your targeting. Make sure the image is .png

Comment: @Malloc Do you have any idea why it can't be changed programmatically?

Comment: 'cause the splash screen is shown before the app delegate will call the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions delegate method. A workaround is to set a splash screen controller from the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` by assigning the controller to the app window.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. Launch Images aren't meant to be dynamic unless it's responding to device orientation.

For more on launch images: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html

The best you can do is, on app launch, use some kind of nice transition from your Launch image to whatever the custom image is that you've downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use default LaunchScreen.xib neither LaunchImage in image.xcassets because there is no code execution on both ways.

Last time, I did it by using intermediate ViewController that will present the actual ViewController.

So, the intermediate ViewController will have constructor something like:

```
-(instancetype)initWithMainViewController:(ViewController*)vc;
```

then on `viewDidLoad`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad;
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
// assuming your downloaded image will always be stored in Documents/dynamicDefaultImage.png
NSString* downloadedImagePath =     [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dynamicDefaultImage.png"];
    if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:downloadedImagePath] ) {
        [_imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:downloadedImagePath]];
    } else {
    // prepare built in image in case your download failed.
        [_imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"builtInLaunchImage"]];
    }

    // present the actual VC after certain delay
    [self performSelector:@selector(loadActualVc) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}

- (void)loadActualVc;
{
    [self presentViewController:_mainViewController animated:YES completion:^{
        // clear the image so that this VC will just be empty VC once main view controller is presented.
        [_imageView setImage:nil];
    }];
}
```

The time taken to load is very minimal compared to default LaunchImage that being called before AppDelegate finish launching. Besides, memory consumption will be kept on minimum too as the image is being unloaded once actual view controller is presented. I think it is worth it if you really have weekly/monthly update of landing page.

Answer (score -1):

yes , offcourse you can change your LunchImage

just go to your `Images.xcassets` folder there are two option `AppIcon` and `LaunchImage` , click on LaunchImage , drag and drop the image you want to .

Note :- Be careful about the size of the image you droping down , otherwise it give a  some error like `The app icon set named "AppIcon" did not have any applicable content`.

Comment: This isn't what they are after -1 they want to be able to download and replace the launch image so on next start up the image will be different, so no need to change add a new submit an update to the app store for just altering the launch image