# Alternate LaunchImage for different application start

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, xib, launchimage

I have developed an application with the new `LaunchImage.xib` feature of Xcode 6. This LaunchImage is simply a blank view with the color of the upcoming rootViewController. This works really fine for normal application startup.

The application can also be started with the *Open In...* option when tapping on a file in other applications (such as dropbox, or a mail attachment) and the given file is then processed in `AppDelegate.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. This may take some time depending on the size of the file. For that kind of application start I would like to show an alternate LaunchImage which informs the user that the file is being processed.

What I have seen so far is that I can only have one `LaunchImage.xib` and there is no way to work with a custom class to execute some code in appDelegate such as simply showing/hiding some labels on that screen.

Are there any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862907/how-to-replace-the-current-launch-image/26864617#26864617 ?

Comment: You should look to using Launch Storyboards, then you can have a controller that manages all of that

Comment: @DanielGalasko: Good point, I will look into that. Thanks

Comment: following on from some discussions with the community it still seems that you can't alternate images since you can't technically connect your launch storyboard to a controller

Comment: @DanielGalasko Yes, that's my point of knowledge, too so far. I was hoping to get some new ideas because I don't think I'm the only one with this type of requirement.

Comment: I've done this by putting code into the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. What I basically do is swap the self.window.rootViewController with my custom viewController (complete with labels, animation etc), then point it back afterwards (in my case, after the user has tapped the screen).

Comment: Launch images are meant to be static and you can have different images for different devices ..If you want to change it you can change during the packaging of the app so I suggest you to do some kind of transition from your Launchimage.xib